# how to fill in textComposer body with text from Text Fields

Tags: ios, sms, uitextfield, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

One of the functions of my app involves the user filling out three seperate text Fields ( bookingName, Guests and date), then sending the text in these Fields via sms using text composer. I am having trouble getting the text from these views into the body. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender {

    MFMessageComposeViewController *textComposer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [textComposer setMessageComposeDelegate:self];
    if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
        [textComposer setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"XXXXXXX"]];
        [textComposer setBody:@"Booking Name: ,\nGuests: ,\n Date: .   "];


        [self presentViewController:textComposer animated:YES completion:NULL];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Can't Open Text");
    }
}

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result

{
    switch (result) {

        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

I just dont know what to put in the "[textComposer setBody:" part,

I have tried so many different ways to no effect.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What are the ways you have tried? Have you tried using NSString stringWithFormat: method?

Comment: All done with NSString stringWithFormat method. Thanks verbumdei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a string for the message body first.

```
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Booking Name: %@,\nGuests: %@,\n Date: %@.   ", bookingName, guestCount, bookingDate];
[textComposer setBody:body];
```

Comment: Why the down votes? Please explain what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: thanks rmaddy, used your advice and it was successful. just had to change bookingname to bookingname.text, guestCount to guestcount.text, bookingDate to bookingdate.text];
thanks for your help, unfortunately i cant vote yet otherwise you would get +1 from me. Thanks again

Comment: The variable names I used were just meant to be place holders for whatever string values you had.